# How do I put my images from Core Data into a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I'm relatively new to Xcode and I want to put images I have in CoreData to be shown in an image slider(uicollectionview). The image slider works just fine with some images I reference within an array, but I want to use the images from core data. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrAllpost = [post]()

struct post{

    var Images:[UIImage]
 }

func fetchData(){

   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
                             AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: 
   "PhotoData")

do {
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for dict in results 
    {
         let imagestr = dict["ImagesName"] as! String
         let array = imagestr.components(separatedBy: ", ") // store image 
     in directory and save image name with comma separated in one string 
          in core data and then that string split by comma and store in 
       name array then load that imagename's image from directory

       let arrPostImages = NSMutableArray()
        for i in array
        {
           let postimage = loadImageFromDirectory(str: i)  //get image from 
                                                              directory
           arrPostImages.add(postimage)
        }
       arrAllPost.append(post(Images: arrPostImages))
     }

}catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.debugDescription)
}
}
 // tableview delegate method
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
      Int) -> Int {
        return arrAllPost.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
         IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tablePost.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", 
      for: indexPath)

                    let item = arrAllPost[indexPath.row] as! Post
                      for img in item.Images
                     {
                              cell.postimageView.image = img
                      }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: you are save images in core data ,after some times app hang ,so store image in document directory and load from directory.

Comment: For this line: let imagestr = dict["ImagesName"] as! String. I get an error that says "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts" @Ruchi

Comment: i save all image name in coredata ,so i used value type as string.